# zmq_poll not listening on signal when reading from stdin

Tags: c++, signals, zeromq, polling

I am using a call to **`zmq_poll`** on Linux, in my C++ app, to poll from reading from console input. Right now I am not using any ZeroMQ sockets but I will in the next future.

As per my understanding **`zmq_poll`** ONLY on Linux can use linux file descriptor including **`STDIN_FILENO`**.

I was expecting the code below to return an **`EINTR`** when I send a CTRL-C to my application.

When I debug it, I can see  that it keeps on waiting until end of timeout and it returns **`res_num=0`**.

```
   zmq_pollitem_t* mpPollItems = new zmq_pollitem_t[1];
   std::memset(mpPollItems,0,sizeof(zmq_pollitem_t));

    mpPollItems[0].socket = NULL;
    mpPollItems[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    mpPollItems[0].events = ZMQ_POLLIN;

    // Poll for events some milliseconds
    int res_num = zmq_poll (mpPollItems, 1, 10000);
```

**`zmq_poll`** is using a linux 'poll' behind the scenes.

Am I doing something wrong with this code or did I misunderstand something in the way `zmq_poll` works?

Could it be something to do with signal masking?

Note: I am calling zmq_poll in a separate thread I spawn from the main.
I did the test using directly 'poll' and I get the same result. I can only see the signal delivered only if 'poll' is called in the main thread; if it is called on a separate thread there is no reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more recent ZeroMQ API extensions have brought a few "dirty" tricks, going **outside** of the original **Zen-of-ZERO**.

Yes, the extended use of O/S-native TCP-peers under a **`ZMQ_STREAM`** Scalable Formal Communication Pattern archetype, became possible, but these steps start to have problems of inconsistent expectation-v/s-reality delivered.

The native O/S-file-descriptor may get imperatively injected into the **`.fd`** item of the `zmq_pollitems_t` **`struct`**(s), yet the **`EINTR`** signal get raised for ZeroMQ-`Socket()`-instances upon propagated O/S-signals, which does not seem to work the same way for "injected"-only polling.

If the same difference persists also the "complete"-setup ( using a fully configured and setup **`ZMQ_STREAM`**-`Socket()`-instance, not a just ad-hoc, `.fd`-"injected"-only trick ) polling, best raise a change-request for the package maintainers, so as to refactor the handling back to the Zen-of-Zero uniform mode for both types of polled-devices.

Comment: Fair enough. I do have a zeromq socket in the zmq_pollitems_t and now  seems ok to me. For the issue of the separate thread I updated my knowledge on Linux and I learnt that signals are delivered ONLY to one thread of the main in use by the process. In my case it was the main one and it explains why the separate thread doesn't listen to any signal. Thanks for your help.